# Create user dashboard and add more user attributes to Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, user-profile

I have used the 'Devise' gem provided by Rails to for user SignUp/Log In. By default it provides 'email', 'password' and 'password confirmation' fields. I wish to add more fields like 'Nickname', 'City', 'Company' etc and then also create a user profile page (Dashboard) which simply displays this information.

Can you please tell me in detail(at least mention the steps) as to how I can achieve this?

Comment: Take a basic Rails tutorial and you'll learn how to add attributes to a model...

Comment: You can find all about this in the excellent guide to `devise` https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 0):

As Iceman stated, you can find how to add parameters at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise. You will have to generate the views and edit the forms to include your parameters. Then the "lazy way" is too add the following code in your Application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
  end
end
```

To create a profile page, you can just add an action to one of your existing controllers or one of the devise controllers.